# NuGet package not in Package Manager search results

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

We have a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bridge) that refuses to appear in the **NuGet Package Manager** search results within Visual Studio. Searching for `Bridge.NET` should return [results](https://www.nuget.org/packages/bridge).

[image]

Initially we thought this might just caching issue, so we waited a few releases, but the problem continues. Here's a copy of the `.nuspec` file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/10/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata minClientVersion="2.5">
        <id>Bridge</id>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
        <title>Bridge.NET</title>
        <authors>Object.NET, Inc.</authors>
        <iconUrl>http://speed.bridge.net/identity/bridgedotnet-100x100.png</iconUrl>
        <owners />
        <licenseUrl>https://github.com/bridgedotnet/Bridge/blob/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
        <projectUrl>http://bridge.net</projectUrl>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Write modern mobile and web apps in C#. Run them anywhere with JavaScript.

WARNING: Installing this package will remove references to System.* and Microsoft.* within your project as they will cause compiler conflicts with Bridge.NET.</description>
        <summary>Write modern mobile and web apps in C#. Run them anywhere in JavaScript with Bridge.NET.</summary>
        <copyright>Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Object.NET, Inc. (http://object.net/). All rights reserved.</copyright>
        <tags>bridge bridge.net js javascript C# csharp mobile ios asp.net aspnet mvc aspnetmvc web transpiler compiler object.net</tags>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
        <frameworkAssemblies>
        </frameworkAssemblies>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

If the search is made directly on [NuGet.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=bridge.net), the correct results are returned. As well, there are no issues with the **Package Manager Console**.

Any help diagnosing this problem would be greatly appreciated. Is there a trick to getting a package listed within the search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package manager will filter out packages if they are not compatible with the project trying to consume them. Your problem could be the fact that the dll's in your NuGet package are a higher .NET version than the project trying to consume them. That would cause them to not appear in the package manager search results

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. After adding a `/lib/net45/` folder to the NuGet package, the project appeared in the search results. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.